# Missing SOAPAction header when invoking WS with Camel-CXF

Tags: web-services, apache-camel, cxf, jax-ws, jbossfuse

We are trying to a invoke Soap service using Camel-Cxf/Fuse and using Payload dataformat. Some times client is rejecting request saying SOAPAction is missing and this is intermittent. Is there a way for us to set SOAPAction specifically during service invocation? In what cases we fail to send SOAPAction? Here is the configuration we are using for invocation.

```
<!-- CXF configuration pointing to WSDL URL and service Name -->

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="abcSOAPCPOutbound"
                         wsdlURL="wsdl/FooService.wsdl"
                         endpointName="cNS:FooServiceSoap"
                         serviceName="cNS:FooService"
                         address="http://example.com/processRequest.asmx"
                         xmlns:cNS="http://www.example.com"
                         loggingFeatureEnabled="false">
            <cxf:inInterceptors>
                <ref bean="GZIPInInterceptor"/>
            </cxf:inInterceptors>     
            <cxf:outInterceptors>           
                <ref bean="iuABCSOAPOutboundInterceptor"/>        
            </cxf:outInterceptors>       
        </cxf:cxfEndpoint> 

    <!-- Came route for invoking service with operationName header set  -->

    <route id="iuFooOutboundRoute">
                <from uri="direct-vm:iuOutboundtoFoo"/>     
                <setHeader headerName="operationName" >
                    <constant>FooSync</constant>
                </setHeader>
                <convertBodyTo type="String"/> 
                <!-- Send to Colibrium -->
                <to uri="cxf:bean:abcSOAPCPOutbound?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"/> 
        <process ref="extractHTTPStatusCode"/>
    </route>
```

Does it cause any problem if we set camel header as SOAPAction before invoking service?

Comment: I don't think there will be any problems as this seems to be the official way to go, regarding the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html) which states at the end "It is noted that the default CXF dispatch client does not send a specific SOAPAction header. Therefore, when the target service requires a specific SOAPAction value, it is supplied in the Camel header using the key SOAPAction (case-insensitive)."

Comment: What's the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

The same way as you do operationName:

```
<setHeader headerName="SOAPAction">
    <constant>DummyOperation</constant>
</setHeader>
```

You can refer here - http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078883/open-source-tools/java-tip-write-an-soa-integration-layer-with-apache-camel.html?page=4